# how to print in c#? i want to print a table(query)

Tags: c#, sql-server, printing, crystal-reports

An Administrator needs to run a report that details when a specific user signs in and out over a historical date range.  The information is saved to a database.

I need to print this information.  It will include his information (name, street, registration, etc) plus all of the sign in/out details.

What is the best way to print with a connection to sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward way of printing is to create either a Crystal Report (as you've tagged as such) or (my preference) a Microsoft Reporting Services Report, that takes the user ID as a parameter, and executes a stored procedure or a parameterized query to get it's data.

You can then either export or print, with either of these reporting APIs, without actually having to show the report on the screen.

Comment: I disagree with the words "straightforward" and "Crystal Report" being used in the same sentence.  However, +1 for the MSRS reference.

Comment: @Chris - straightforwardish, but yes, SSRS is much easier!